# what is the difference between a computed and a function in knockoutjs

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Let's say I have a viewModel like this:

```
function ViewModel() {
    var $t = this;
    this.a = ko.observable(5);
    this.f = function(val) { 
        return $t.a() * (val === 'simple' ? 2: 10);
    };
    this.c = ko.computed(function() { 
        return $t.a() * 20; 
    }); 
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

and HTML like this:

```
<div><input data-bind="value: a"/></div>
<div data-bind="text: f('simple')"></div>
<div data-bind="text: f('complex')"></div>
<div data-bind="text: c"></div>
```

this results in this initial page (the [5] depicts an input field):

```
[5]
10
50
100
```

When I change the 5 in the input field into 10 I see this:

```
[10]
20
100
200
```

So the bindings work. See a working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/1vrz71fs/2/.

What I want to understand is the difference between using `ko.computed(...)` and a plain old function, they both seem to work just fine. Are there are cons / pros of using the one over the other. The function approach seems to be much more convenient since it accepts parameters which the `ko.computed` doesn't let me do...

Answer (score 1):

In this case, there's no difference because Knockout is creating a computed observable to wrap the function for you. When the value is just something you're going to display in the UI, either way is fine.

It does make a difference when you want to customize the behavior of the observable. For example, rate limiting updates or excluding the value from a server postback aren't possible with the function form. The documentation page for [computed observables](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html) explains these situations pretty well.